# DRY up java (lambda functions?)

Tags: java, lambda, dry

I'm writing a program in java that essentially tests a bunch of things...

For every call, I need to check for `NullPointerExceptions`, `StackOverflow`, `IndexOutOfBounds`, etc...

I have this repeating pattern in each of my methods now:

```
try {
  doSomething();
} catch(NullPointerExceptions npe) {
  // prints something
} catch(StackOverflow soe) {
  // prints something
} catch(IndexOutOfBounds iob) {
  // prints something
}
```

Since I may call `doSomething()` (with different params) multiple times in a single method, I can't just `throw` the exception back up to main (because I need the next test to actually run).

I'd like to write a lambda tester that I can pass a function to, but I can't find a way to do this with java :(.

I'd like to do something like:

```
private void test(Method m, E expectedValue) {
  try {
    if(!m.run().equals(expectedValue))
      System.out.println("FAILED TEST: "+m.name()+". Value was "+m.run()+", should have been "+expectedValue);
  } catch() {
    // see above
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you use JUnit? That does this more or less for you.

Comment: no, JUnit is just not feasible in this case, or else I'd be using it...

Comment: I don't get the problem. And also don't see why JUnit is not fit.

Comment: While you're at it, you should also catch an ArithmeticException, an OutOfMemoryError, an IllegalArgumentException, definitely a ClassCastException, and maybe even a ConcurrentModificationException. OR you could just use a testing framework...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do in Java is to use an interface:

```
interface DoSomething<E extends Comparable<E>> {
  E doSomething();
}
```

Then your `test` method can look like this:

```
private void test(DoSomething<E> m, E expectedValue) {
  try {
    if(!m.doSomething().equals(expectedValue))
      System.out.println("FAILED TEST");
  } catch() {
    //handle exception
  }
}
```

`E` needs to extend `Comparable<E>` because you are calling `equals` inside of `test`.

This is called a SAM (single abstract method) interface.  Using SAM classes and interfaces to simulate lambdas is a common occurence in Java.  I've even heard them called "SAMbdas".

**EDIT:** My solution does not necessarily involve modifying existing classes:

```
DoSomething foo = new DoSomething<String>() {
     public String doSomething() { return "Hello World"; }
};
test(foo, "Hello World");
```

Comment: Yet this has the drawback that existing classes must be modified (i.e. implement DoSomething) which is not always possible (or desirable).

Comment: @Ingo I disagree. You can use an anonymous inner class in a similar way to your solution.  See my edit.

Comment: @dbyme - Indeed, I stand corrected. Looks like you deserve your +1. :)

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas are unfortunately not yet present in java. But you can use generic java.util.concurrent.Callable:

```
private <T> void test(Callable<T> c, T expectedValue) {
      try {
        if(!c.call().equals(expectedValue))
          System.out.println("FAILED TEST: "+c+". Value was "+c.call()+", should have been "+expectedValue);
      } catch(Exception ex) {
        // see above
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It could go like this:

```
abstract class Method<R> {
     public R run();
}


test(new Method<Result1>() {
         public Result1 run() { .... }
     }, expectedResult);
```

Comment: Comparable<R> or Comparable<E>? or just Comparable for that matter?

Comment: In Ingo's answer `Comparable<R>`, in my answer `Comparable<E>` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are going to work their way into JDK7.  If you want to try it out, grab one of the early access releases from Oracle

http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335

That said, I don't quite understand the problem.  Can you add an example of how you intend to all these methods?  Your suggested method sounds like it is on the right track, try:

```
private void test(Method m, Object target, Object[] args, E expectedValue) {
  try {
    if(!m.invoke(target, args).equals(expectedValue))
      System.out.println("FAILED TEST: "+m.name()+". Value was "+m.run()+", should have been "+expectedValue);
  } catch() {
    // see above
  }
}
```

Gus Bosman is right, though.  A unit testing framework like JUnit would probably help a lothere.

Comment: JUnit is not exclusively available for your machine. For example I'm using it too

Comment: no... I can't use JUnit for this, but I also can't use a pre-release java because its on multiple machiens

Comment: Lambdas are *not* going into java SE 7.  Probably in SE 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write this yourself, and not JUnit, you could use Reflection to call the method.

So, instead of saying `m.run()` you would use `java.lang.reflect.Method#invoke`:

```
try {
  method.invoke(obj, arg1, arg2,...);
} catch (Exception e) {
  // there are several Reflection exceptions you also need to deal with
}
```